# Half and double angle

Tags: trigonometry

when I know that $tan(\frac{x}{2})$ is, then what is $tan(x)$ ?

I recently have seen a formula for this, but I can't fit it and I do not remember how to get it :)

Thank you.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities)

Answer (score 0):

Use the double angle formula:

$$
tan(2y) = \frac{2 * tan(y)}{1 - tan^2(y)}
$$

In your case, $ y = \frac{x}{2} $